# Ical / Apple calendar integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, icalendar, caldav

I am trying to fetch the user's calendar details from iCloud for rails application using the server URL (caldav.icloud.com) via calDav client. I tested with few accounts, and I was able get the calendar details successfully using this server URL.
I want to confirm if I can access all calendars using this URL itself or is there any possibility that the server URL can vary ?
BACK-END - RUBY ON RAILS

Answer (score 3):

Apple partially supports the CalDAV standard in their iCloud calendar.  As far as I know, there is no official support - there is no information on the caldav support originating from Apple itself.

While it's possible to communicate with `caldav.icloud.com` using DAV, the calendars are having different URLs.  A calendar-URLs in icloud looks like `https://p12-caldav.icloud.com/17112341234/calendars/nameofthecalendar`.  Those numbers (`p12` and `17112341234` in the example) will always be the same for all calendars owned by the same user.

To find those numbers, it's possible to do a PROPFIND on `https://caldav.icloud.com` asking for current_user_principal.
Unfortunately I have no clue how to do that through Ruby.  (I'm the maintainer of the Python caldav client library, so I know how to easily do this in Python though).